# Метод getContentResolver().update(...) не обновляет значения

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток.
Есть кусок кода:

```
ContentValues value = new ContentValues();              
value.put(Contacts.People.DISPLAY_NAME, "ФИО");
getContentResolver().update(Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI, value, Contacts.People._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}); //id - long типа
```

Вроде бы всё соответствует, как в примере [от разработчиков Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html). Однако выдается ошибка:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot update URL: content://contacts/people

Подскажите, что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 1):

Класс `Contacts.People` [объявлен deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.People.html) - устаревшим, теперь там даже такого поля как `_ID` нет, так что советую вместо `Contacts.People._ID` использовать `ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID`

Comment: я с вами согласен. это актуально для android версий > 1.6
а у меня как раз именно 1.6, так что там такого и в помине нет
что делать?